# Prove $f(a,b,c)\le f\left(\frac{a+b}{2},\frac{a+b}{2},c\right)$

Tags: inequality, radicals, maxima-minima, mixing-variables

Given non-negative real numbers $a,b,c$ which sum is $2.$ Assume that $c=min\{a,b,c\}.$

Denote $$f(a,b,c)=\frac{\sqrt{2ab+7}+\sqrt{2bc+7}+\sqrt{2ca+7}}{\sqrt{abc+9}}.$$
Prove that $f(a,b,c)\le f(t,t,c),$ where $t=\dfrac{a+b}{2}.$

I've tried to use Cauchy inequality without success.

Indeed, we have

$$f\left(\frac{a+b}{2},\frac{a+b}{2},c\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\dfrac{(a+b)^2}{2}+7}+\sqrt{c(a+b)+7}+\sqrt{c(a+b)+7}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{(a+b)^2}{4}c+9}}.$$

Now, it's true by Cauchy that $\sqrt{2bc+7}+\sqrt{2ca+7}\le 2\sqrt{ac+bc+7} \iff \sqrt{2bc+7}.\sqrt{2ca+7}\le ac+bc+7. $

And $\sqrt{2ab+7}\le \sqrt{\dfrac{(a+b)^2}{2}+7}.$ Thus, it's enough to show $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{abc+9}}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{(a+b)^2}{4}c+9}},$$which is equivalent to $(a+b)^2\le 4ab.$

It is reverse inequality. Hope you help me continue my thoughts. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any guarantee that this is true? Either way, I will first try to treat each summand separately:
$$\dfrac{2ab+7}{abc+9} = \dfrac{2 + \frac{7}{ab}}{c+\frac{9}{ab}}=...$$
and see if you can do the same estimate.

Comment: @Dragon boy What is an original problem?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I tried prove $f(a,b,c)\le \dfrac{2\sqrt{7}+3}{3}$ by using MV.

Comment: @Dragonboy It seems ugly hmm.

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that:
$f(a,b,c)\geq0,$ where $$f(a,b,c)=\frac{2\sqrt7+3}{3}\sqrt{abc+9}-\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{2ab+7}.$$
Let $c=\min\{a,b,c\}.$

Thus, $0\leq c\leq\frac{2}{3}$ and by Jensen and AM-GM we obtain:  $$f(a,b,c)-f\left(\frac{a+b}{2},\frac{a+b}{2},c\right)=-\frac{2\sqrt7+3}{3}\left(\sqrt{\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2c+9}-\sqrt{abc+9}\right)+$$
$$+\left(2\sqrt{(a+b)c+7}-\sqrt{2ac+7}-\sqrt{2bc+7}\right)+\left(\sqrt{\frac{(a+b)^2}{2}+7}-\sqrt{2ab+7}\right)=$$
$$=-\tfrac{\frac{2\sqrt7+3}{3}\cdot \frac{(a-b)^2c}{4}}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2c+9}+\sqrt{abc+9}}+\tfrac{\left(\sqrt{2ac+7}-\sqrt{2bc+7}\right)^2}{2\sqrt{(a+b)c+7}+\sqrt{2ac+7}+\sqrt{2bc+7}}+\tfrac{\frac{(a-b)^2}{2}}{\left(\sqrt{\frac{(a+b)^2}{2}+7}+\sqrt{2ab+7}\right)}=$$
$$=(a-b)^2\left(-\tfrac{(2\sqrt7+3)c}{12\left(\sqrt{\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2c+9}+\sqrt{abc+9}\right)}+\tfrac{4c^2}{\left(2\sqrt{(a+b)c+7}+\sqrt{2ac+7}+\sqrt{2bc+7}\right)\left(\sqrt{2ac+7}+\sqrt{2bc+7}\right)^2}+\tfrac{1}{2\left(\sqrt{\frac{(a+b)^2}{2}+7}+\sqrt{2ab+7}\right)}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq(a-b)^2\left(-\tfrac{(2\sqrt7+3)c}{12\left(\sqrt{\left(\frac{2-c}{2}\right)^2c+9}+\sqrt{c^3+9}\right)}+\tfrac{4c^2}{4\sqrt{(2-c)c+7}\left(2\sqrt{(2-c)c+7}\right)^2}+\tfrac{1}{4\sqrt{\frac{(2-c)^2}{2}+7}}\right).$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: We need to prove $(a-b)^2.f(c)\ge 0.$ I am trying to prove $f(c)>0.$

Comment: Yes. It's true.

Comment: I accepted your answer. Thanks again.